# How can we find a basis for the intersection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

We have the vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$ 
$$A=\{(x,y,2z,z) \mid x, y, z\in \mathbb{R}\}=\{x(1,0,0,0)+y(0,1,0,0)+z(0,0,2,1)\mid x, y, z\in \mathbb{R}\}$$ 
$$B=\{(x,y,z,y)\mid x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}\}=\{x(1,0,0,0)+y(0,1,0,1)+z(0,0,1,0)\mid x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

A basis of $A$ is therefore, $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),  (0,0,2,1)\}$, so it is of dimension $3$.

A basis of $B$ is therefore, $\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,1), (0,0,1,0)\}$, so it is of dimension $3$.

Right?

How can we find a basis and the dimension of $A\cap B$ ?

Is the sum $A+B$ all the sums $a+b$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ ? And how can we find a basis and the dimension?

Comment: Just write all 6 Basis vectors in one matrix and calculate the rank, the remaining vectors which arent zero are your basis.

Comment: So  that a vector is in the intersection it must be in both A and B. When find the linearly independent of all 6 vectors, will they be in the intersection? @user160069

Comment: suppose $x \in A \cap B$ so $x=\sum k_ib_i$ $b_i$ basis of B and $x=\sum  k'_ia_i$ $a_i$ basis of A, now x=x,...

Comment: So, $x=a_1(1,0,0,0)+a_2 (0,1,0,0)+a_3  (0,0,2,1)$ and $x=b_1(1,0,0,0)+b_2 (0,1,0,1)+b_3 (0,0,1,0)$. @user160069

Comment: Do we have to find all the possible coefficients? @user160069

Comment: Yes. you can now bring it to one side and write it as a Matrix.

Comment: We have that $$a_1-b_1=0, a_2-b_2=0, 2a_3-b_3=0, a_3-b_2=0$$ 
In a matrix form it is as follows: $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &-1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 &0 & 0 &-1\\ 0 & 0 &1 & 0 &-1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\ a_2\\ a_3 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ 
@user160069

Comment: We have that $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &-1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 &0 & 0 &-1\\ 0 & 0 &1 & 0 &-1&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &-1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 &0 & 0 &-1\\ 0 & 0 &0 & 0 &2&-1\end{pmatrix}$$  @user160069

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector $u = (x, y, z, t) \in A \cap B$ iff $z=2t$ and $y=t$. This makes a system of 2 equations in the 4 unknown $x, y, z, t$. This system has rank 2 and one can write $u = (x, t, 2t, t)$ where $x, t$ are arbitrary parameters. Thus
$u = x (1,0,0,0) + t (0,1,2,1)$. This gives the required basis.

$A+B$ is indeed the sum of all $a+b$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. It is also the set of all linear combinations $x a + y b$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and
$a\in A$ and $b \in B$. A basis of $A + B$ is very easy to find in your example because $(1, 0, 0, 0)\in A \subset (A+B)$, the same for $(0,1,0,0)$. Similarly, $(0,0,1,0)\in B$ and one has

$$(0,0,0,1) = (0,0,2,1) - 2 (0,0,1,0)\in A+B$$

Hence the whole usual basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ belongs to $A+B$, so $A+B = \mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: How exactly have you found the basis for $A+B$ ? Since it is the set of all linear combinations $xa+yb$ it is the set of $$a_1(1,0,0,0)+a_2 (0,1,0,0)+a_3 (0,0,2,1)+b_1(1,0,0,0)+b_2(0,1,0,1)+b_3(0,0,1,0)$$

Comment: I guess and I prove that all the vectors of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ are in $A+B$. It implies that $A+B=\mathbb{R}^4$ because it cannot be larger than $\mathbb{R}^4$. Hence the standard basis is also a basis of $A+B$.

Comment: Is each subspace with dimension $4$ equal to $\mathbb{R}^4$ ? And is therefore  a basis is the standars one?

Comment: Yes every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dimension $n$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$. More generally, if a subspace is included in another subspace and they have the same dimension, they are equal.

Comment: Since $A$ and $B$ are vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$, then $A+B$ is also a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$, right?

Comment: yes a sum of two or more subspaces is a subspace.

Comment: I got it!! :-) I want to find also a vector subspace $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $A\oplus C=\mathbb{R}^4$. This means that the sum of $A$ and $C$ must the $\mathbb{R}^4$ and the intersection $A\cap C$ must be empty, or not? How can we find such a $C$ ? Do we have to extend $A$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: The intersection of 2 subspaces can never be empty because it contains 0, but it can be reduced to $\{0\}$. You can obtain C by extending A's basis with a 4th independent vector.

Comment: Which is exactly the definition of $\oplus$ ? To extend $A$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ we add the vector $(0,0,0,1)$, right? So is $C=\{(0,0,0,1)\}$ ? 
So, we get that $A\oplus C=\{(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),  (0,0,2,1), (0,0,0,1)\}$ ? Is this $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: You're starting mistaking a subspace for a basis. They are two different things. The sets you wrote are not $C$ and $A\oplus C$ but the basis of these subspaces. Look at the way you described $A$ and $B$ in your question.

Comment: So, does it hold that $C=\{\lambda (0,0,0,1)\mid \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}$ ? Having extended $A$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, so that $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),  (0,0,2,1), (0,0,0,1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$, do we conclude that $A\oplus C=\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: It is true. Make sure you're able to prove that $A \cap C = \{0\}$.

Comment: I showed that $A\cap C=\{0\}$. So this mean that $$A\oplus C=\left \{x  (
1, 0, 0, 0 )+y( 0 , 1, 0 ,0)+z( 0, 0, 2, 1)+w ( 0, 0, 0, 1) \mid x,y,z,w\in \mathbb{R}\right \}$$ right? Is this equal to $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: Yes to both questions. The dimension of $A\oplus C$ is the dimension of $A$ plus the dimension of $C$.

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much!! :-)